# SqlServer Full Text Search - timeouts when approaching 89% of memory

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I using SqlServer 2014 for Full Text Search capability. I noticed behavior that reproducing itself constantly:

When machine running SqlServer approaching 89% of allocated memory (e.g. about 10% free memory left) - FTS stops working and I begin getting timeouts. Constantly.

Interesting, that I tested this on several machines with different amount of RAM (4GB, 8GB) - and the behavior is always the same - magical 89% memory barrier, which makes me thinking that this is something configurable.

Can someone clarify me please how exactly this works?